# How can I print out the first line of all the files that match certain "find" criteria?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, find

I'd like to print out the first line of each `.txt` file that is more than a 100 bytes. So far, I've managed to gather the files that match the criteria but I don't know how to print out the files' first line of text.

```
find -size +100c -name "*.txt"
```

Or am I on the wrong track completely?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to run `head -n 1` on each file:

```
find . -size +100c -name '*.txt' -execdir head -n 1 {} \;
```

or, if your `find` doesn’t support `-execdir`,

```
find . -size +100c -name '*.txt' -exec head -n 1 {} \;
```

If your `head` version supports `-q`, or you don’t care about the headers shown for each file when multiple files are processed in one invocation, you can make both variants slightly more efficient using

```
… -exec head -q -n 1 {} +
```

(See [Race Conditions with `-exec`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Race-Conditions-with-_002dexec.html) to understand the benefits of `-execdir`.)

Answer (score 4):

You'll often see `xargs` suggested to work on the output of `find`

```bash
find -size +100c -name "*.txt" | xargs head -n 1
```

xargs takes the list of *filenames* produced by find, and provides the filenames as arguments to the given command. It does this intelligently to avoid "too many arguments" or "command too long" errors.

You might want to use `head -q -n1` if you don't want the extra information head offers when given multiple filenames.

---

Since a filename can contain almost any character (including newline), this is a safer invocation of find|xargs:

```bash
find -size +100c -name "*.txt" -print0 | xargs -0 head -n 1
```

- the `-print0` directive outputs the filenames separated by a null byte instead of the default newline
- the xargs `-0` option uses a null byte as the argument separator instead of the default newline.

Comment: You could also consider adding `-r` to the arguments of `xargs` so that the command won't appear to hang (waiting on stdin) if it happens there are no files satisfying the criterion.